# I am only good in bullet. Why?

Tags: lichess, bullet-chess

I am 2100 in lichess bullet (1+0) and 1500-1700 to anything else. Why does it happen?

Answer (score 2):

If you play mostly bullet you will be better at bullet.  Bullet restricts the depth of thinking to a very small amount of time which means its easier for one to make a mistake for the opponent to capitalize on.  Increase the time length that someone can make their plans their position becomes harder to capitalize on.

Article if your interested in a GM's perspective.
https://chessmood.com/blog/does-bullet-chess-make-you-better